# Templates and inlining- optimizing multiplication

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, inline-assembly

I don't understand this example I came across:

> ```
> int Multiply(int x, int m){
>     return x * m;}
>
> template<int m>
> int MultiplyBy(int x){
>     return x * m;}
>
> int a,b;
> a = Multiply(10,8);
> b = MultiplyBy<8>(10);
> ```
>
> In the above example the template function is faster than the simple
>   function because the compiler knows that it can multiply by a power of
>   2 by using a shift operation. x*8 is replaced by x << , which is
>   faster. In the case of the simple function, the compiler doesnt know
>   the value of m and therefore cannot do the optimization **unless the
>   function can be inlined**.

As I understand it, the reason the template can optimize is because the compiler knows the value of the argument (8) at compile-time, whereas the simple function will not know the value of x (or m) until run-time. So how is inlining the simple function going to change this fact? Inlining doesn't provide any run-time knowledge of the argument value??

Comment: The template version is faster because you're hard-coding one of the operands. Inlining both versions will produce markedly different code, and a dump-to-assembly and examination of said-same will likely reveal this. Will it further be enhanced since it is a power of two? Perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Inlining doesn't provide any run-time knowledge of the argument value??

Inlining per se doesn't. However, since the second argument is a compile-time constant, the compiler can propagate that constant into the inlined function.

Since the first argument is also a compile-time constant, the entire

```
a = Multiply(10,8);
```

can be replaced with

```
a = 80;
```

In fact, this is precisely what my compiler (gcc 4.7.2) does when I turn on optimizations.

Comment: In fact, it does more optimizations than just the above complete elimination of the multiplication when _both_ args are compile-time constants. For example, if _one_ argument is compile-time constant, on some x86 CPUs, it implements the complete table from section 9.2 of http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/47414_15h_sw_opt_guide.pdf plus more for other simple decompositions.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Multiply(10,8);
```

Let's manually inline the function call:

```
a = 10 * 8;
```

Now, of course 8 is a compile-time constant here, so the compiler can use the bit-shift optimization as described. However, it would likely perform a better optimization and just replace `10 * 8` with `80`. Compilers are very smart - given a constant expression, such as `10 * 8`, they can work out the result at compile time.

That would be different had you done:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
a = Multiply(10,x);
```

If you inline `Multiply` here, you get:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
a = 10 * x;
```

The compiler doesn't know the value of `x` at compile-time and therefore can't optimize this in the same way.